# SFML movement not working with delta time C++

Tags: c++, sfml

I have a `Player` class that inherits from `RectangleShape` and I have created a function to move my player left and right on the A & D keys, but when enabling and disabling VSync I find that the movement speeds up rapidly, my guess is that my delta time implementation is incorrect but it seems to be the same as most tutorials online:

```
class Player : public sf::RectangleShape {
private:
    sf::Vector2f velocity;
    sf::Vector2f acceleration;
    const float maxSpeed = 20.f;
public:
    Player(sf::Vector2f size) : sf::RectangleShape(size) {
        velocity = sf::Vector2f(0.f, 0.f);
        acceleration = sf::Vector2f(0.05f, 27.f);
    }

    void Move(int& dt) {
        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::D)) {
            if (velocity.x < maxSpeed) {
                velocity.x += acceleration.x * dt;
            }
        }
        else if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::A)) {
            if (velocity.x > -maxSpeed) {
                velocity.x -= acceleration.x * dt;
            }
        }
        else if (velocity.x < 0.2f && velocity.x > - 0.2f) {
            velocity.x = 0;
        }
        else {
            if (velocity.x > 0.f) {
                velocity.x -= acceleration.x * dt;
            }
            else {
                velocity.x += acceleration.x * dt;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my main loop (stripped down)(I also have a custom `Window` class):

```
sf::Clock dtClock;
int dt;

int main() {
    Window win("Test Window", sf::VideoMode::getDesktopMode().width, sf::VideoMode::getDesktopMode().height, false);
    Player player(sf::Vector2f(50.f, 50.f));
    player.setFillColor(sf::Color::Blue);
    player.move(sf::Vector2f(200.f, 150.f));

    sf::Clock clock;
    float lastTime = 0;

    while (win.IsOpen()) {
        dt = dtClock.restart().asMilliseconds();

        player.Move(dt);
        win.SetCenter(player.getPosition());

        float currentTime = clock.restart().asSeconds();
        short int fps = 1 / currentTime;
        lastTime = currentTime;

        win.Clear();
        win.Draw(player);
        win.Disp(fps);
    }
}
```

EDIT: here is the minimal reproducible code:

```
#include <string>

#define BAR_SIZE 16.f

//this is where scale will be 1:1
#define STANDARD_WIDTH 1920

sf::Font firaCode;

enum class RenderObjectType {
    Rectangle = 0,
    Circle,
    Sprite,
    count
};
typedef RenderObjectType TROT;
struct TestRenderObject { //node
    RenderObjectType type;
    void* val;
    TestRenderObject(void* val, RenderObjectType type) { this->val = val; this->type = type; }
};
typedef TestRenderObject TRO;

class Window {
private:
    std::string title;
    sf::RenderWindow win;
    sf::View view;
    sf::View staticView; //for use with GUI and cinematic bars
    sf::Event evnt;
    sf::Color background;

    bool vsyncEnabled = true;
public:
    Window(std::string name = "", unsigned pWidth = 1920, unsigned pHeight = 1080, bool fullscreen = false, sf::Color backgroundColour = sf::Color(135, 206, 235)) {
        this->title = name;
        this->win.create(sf::VideoMode(pWidth, pHeight), name, (fullscreen ? sf::Style::Fullscreen : sf::Style::Default));
        this->win.setVerticalSyncEnabled(this->vsyncEnabled);
        this->view.setSize(sf::Vector2f(pWidth, pHeight));
        this->view.setCenter(pWidth / 2, pHeight / 2);
        this->staticView.setSize(sf::Vector2f(pWidth, pHeight));
        this->staticView.setCenter(pWidth / 2, pHeight / 2);
        this->background = backgroundColour;
    }
    inline void toggleVSync() {
        this->vsyncEnabled = !this->vsyncEnabled;
        this->win.setVerticalSyncEnabled(this->vsyncEnabled);
    }
    inline void Clear() {
        this->win.clear(background);
        this->win.setView(this->view);
    }
    inline void Draw(sf::RectangleShape& r) {
        this->win.draw(r);
    }
    inline void Draw(sf::CircleShape& c) {
        this->win.draw(c);
    }
    inline void Draw(sf::Sprite& s) {
        this->win.draw(s);
    }
    inline void Draw(std::initializer_list<TestRenderObject>& renderObjects) { //multiple types for debugging
        for (auto& ele : renderObjects) {
            switch (ele.type)
            {
            case(RenderObjectType::Rectangle):
                this->Draw(*((sf::RectangleShape*)ele.val));
                break;
            case(RenderObjectType::Circle):
                this->Draw(*((sf::CircleShape*)ele.val));
                break;
            case(RenderObjectType::Sprite):
                this->Draw(*((sf::Sprite*)ele.val));
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    inline void Draw(std::initializer_list<sf::Sprite> renderObjects) {
        for (auto& ele : renderObjects)
            this->win.draw(ele);
    }
    inline void Disp() {

        this->win.setView(this->staticView); //UI elements


        this->win.setView(this->view); //game elements

        this->win.display();
    }
    inline bool IsOpen() {
        return this->win.isOpen();
    }
    inline bool PollEvnt() {
        return this->win.pollEvent(this->evnt);
    }
    inline sf::Event& GetEvnt() {
        return this->evnt;
    }
    inline sf::Vector2f GetPosition() {
        return sf::Vector2f(this->win.getPosition().x, this->win.getPosition().y);
    }
    inline void Shift(sf::Vector2f amount) {
        this->view.move(amount);
    } inline void Move(sf::Vector2f amount) { this->Shift(amount); }
    inline void SetCenter(sf::Vector2f position) {
        this->view.setCenter(position);
    }
    inline void Rotate(float amount) {
        this->view.rotate(amount);
    }
    inline void Zoom(float amount) {
        this->view.zoom(amount);
    }
    inline void ResetRotation() {
        this->view.setRotation(0);
    }
    inline void ResetZoom() {
        this->view.setSize(sf::Vector2f(this->win.getSize()));
    } inline void ResetScale() { this->ResetZoom(); }
    inline void ResetViewRatio() {
        this->ResetZoom();
    }
    void Close() {
        this->win.close();
    }
};

typedef Window Win;

using Keyboard = sf::Keyboard;

using WinEvnt = sf::Event;


const float gravity{ 1.f };

class Player : public sf::RectangleShape {
private:
    sf::Vector2f velocity;
    sf::Vector2f acceleration;
    const float maxSpeed = 20.f;
    const float maxFallSpeed = 30.f;
public:
    Player(sf::Vector2f size) : sf::RectangleShape(size) {
        velocity = sf::Vector2f(0.f, 0.f);
        acceleration = sf::Vector2f(0.05f, 27.f);
    }

    void Move(const int& dt) {
        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::D)) {
            if (velocity.x < maxSpeed) {
                velocity.x += acceleration.x * dt;
            }
        }
        else if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::A)) {
            if (velocity.x > -maxSpeed) {
                velocity.x -= acceleration.x * dt;
            }
        }
        else if (velocity.x < 0.2f && velocity.x > -0.2f) {
            velocity.x = 0;
        }
        else {
            if (velocity.x > 0.f) {
                velocity.x -= acceleration.x * dt;
            }
            else {
                velocity.x += acceleration.x * dt;
            }
        }

        if (this->getPosition().y >= 500) {
            velocity.y = 0;
            if (this->getPosition().y >= 500)
                this->setPosition(this->getPosition().x, 500);
            if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Space) || Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::W)) {
                velocity.y -= acceleration.y;
            }

        }
        else {
            if (velocity.y < maxFallSpeed)
                velocity.y += gravity;
        }
        this->move(velocity);
    }
};



sf::Clock dtClock;
int dt;

int main() {
    Window win("Test Window", sf::VideoMode::getDesktopMode().width, sf::VideoMode::getDesktopMode().height, false);
    sf::CircleShape c(100.f);
    c.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);
    Player player(sf::Vector2f(50.f, 50.f));
    player.setFillColor(sf::Color::Blue);
    player.move(sf::Vector2f(200.f, 150.f));
    sf::RectangleShape rect(sf::Vector2f(100.f, 50.f));
    rect.setFillColor(sf::Color::Magenta);
    rect.move(sf::Vector2f(600.f, 200.f));
    sf::CircleShape circle(200.f);
    circle.setFillColor(sf::Color::Yellow);
    circle.setOutlineThickness(-15);
    circle.setOutlineColor(sf::Color(255, 99, 200));
    circle.move(sf::Vector2f(1000.f, 1000.f));
    sf::RectangleShape big(sf::Vector2f(6000.f, 3000.f));
    big.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
    big.move(sf::Vector2f(900.f, 600.f));

    std::initializer_list<TestRenderObject> objects =
    {
            TRO((void*)&c, TROT::Circle),
            TRO((void*)&rect, TROT::Rectangle),
            TRO((void*)&big, TROT::Rectangle),
            TRO((void*)&circle, TROT::Circle)
    };

    sf::Clock clock;
    float lastTime = 0;

    while (win.IsOpen()) {
        while (win.PollEvnt()) {
            if (win.GetEvnt().type == WinEvnt::KeyReleased && win.GetEvnt().key.code == Keyboard::V) {
                win.toggleVSync();
            }
            else if (win.GetEvnt().type == sf::Event::Resized) {
                win.ResetViewRatio();
            }
            else if (win.GetEvnt().type == WinEvnt::Closed) {
                win.Close();
            }
        }

        dt = dtClock.restart().asMilliseconds();


        player.Move(dt);
        win.SetCenter(player.getPosition());

        float currentTime = clock.restart().asSeconds();
        short int fps = 1 / currentTime;
        lastTime = currentTime;

        win.Clear();
        win.Draw(objects);
        win.Draw(player);
        win.Disp();
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly does your Disp function do?

Comment: @infinitezero it draws the fps and switches the buffers

Comment: I actually was asking for some code :)

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

With basic drawing code and modern GPUs you can easily get up to 2-3k frames per second, which can then turn into a frame time of `1f / 3000fps = 0.00033s` which is less than one millisecond, thus when you call `asMilliseconds()` you may end up with `0`.

An easy workaround here is to always work with seconds (`asSeconds()`) and floats, that way you should never hit `0`. Keep in mind though, that you should always set a limit, either by enabling VSync or calling `setFramerateLimit()`.

As for a design point of view, I recommend to not derive from `sf::RectangleShape` and instead use [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) over inheritance. You can then derive from the more interface-like classes such as `sf

Comment: all that has done is slow the player down dramatically, the problem still persists

Comment: Maybe, maybe not, in the end relying on milliseconds when the resolution goes down to microseconds and you get a better result by utilizing a `float` instead of an integer, there's not really a down side to adapting the code.